# Find elements in prisma where they have N+ relations with other elements

Tags: prisma

I have a prisma schema defined like:

```
model User {
  id         Int          @id      @default(autoincrement())
  userName   string       @unique
  complaints Complaint[]
}

model Complaint {
  id        Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
  user      User              @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId    Int
  priority ComplaintPriority
}

enum ComplaintPriority {
  HIGH
  MEDIUM
  LOW
}
```

I need to find all the users with at least N complaint with `HIGHT` priority (N variable) but until now I didn't find a way to do it. The ideal is to use the `having` clause of SQL, but I've found documentation about `having` just in the usage of `groupBy`.

Anybody has any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible with a single Prisma query. But it's quite easy with two queries. You would:

1. Use a `groupBy` on the `complaint` table/model to fetch the `userId` values where the count of `HIGH` priority complaints exceeds a certain value.
2. Use those `userId` values to do a `findMany` in the `User` table/model.

This is what it looks like

```js
const userIdGroupBy = await prisma.complaint.groupBy({
        by: ["userId"],
        where: {
            priority: "HIGH"
        },
        having: {
            priority: {
                _count: {
                    gte: _VIOLATION_THRESHOLD_
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
    
    // convert array of objects to array of id values. 
    let userIdArray = userIdGroupBy.map(item => item.userId)  

    let usersWithViolations = await prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
            id: {
                in: userIdArray
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @Tasin Ishman, it looks a very good work around. Do you know how good/bad it will be with performances? Particularly for a big amount of `ids`.

Comment: Happy to help! You can log the generated SQL query that Prisma makes by passing the `query` log level as [instructed here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/pavrisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/logging). The generated SQL for these queries seems quite efficient to me.  That leaves the `map` operation being done inside nodejs.  I don't think this will be too much of an issue either (unless you're dealing with millions of IDs I guess).